# GNU parallel --block and -L clarification

Tags: bioinformatics, gnu-parallel, genetic-programming

Given that I have a file of N size. For the sake of example 30GB file.

Facts about the file content is that it has proprotional amount of lines.
This is interleaved FastQ file. (not important for the question but usefull for someone)

File content is `paired` or `interleaved` DNA sequence of strings. Each `pair` is `8` lines long.

I want to process the interleaved FastQ with `GNU parallel` in order to speed up the process.
Reason for using `parallel` instead of native `bwa` tool threads feature is that `parallel` helps to reduce amount of RAM needed because the nature of `bwa` memory allocation.

Given that interleaved file is 30GB of size I want to process `chunks` of `--block 500M`, command line params looks like `--pipe --block 500M -L 8 -j 10` this then is sent as `stdin` to `bwa` and will run 10 `bwa` tasks each getting `500M` chunks with a `record` of `8` lines.

Is my assumption correct that `--block 500M` and `-L 8` will be managed by `parallel` and I can be certain that my `bwa` tool will always get `8` lines times `N MB` of data?

What I am not clear is, will `parallel` "repeat" last "chunk" if `8` lines are not present?
And will it apropriatelly controll other chunk inputs for `N processes` I start with `parallel`?

Or this `--block 500M` "blindly" sends 500M chunk to single process regardless if last part of the 500M chunk does not contain `8 lines` so to speak?

Update:

After whole day reading questions and answers on biostars and seqanswers I've realised that my testing/"benchmarking" was wrong.

But this helped to realise that I need to update the question and will make separate question.

I was testing inside Docker container which by default has very low `/dev/shm` thus I have mislead my self to go totaly different path.

---

Comment: parallel is a cook tool but _if_ your need to  manage the fastsq, the mapping, the downstream BAM files, VCF files, you should use a workflow manager (nextflow, snakemake).

Comment: @Pierre Yes it is clear that processing in Genomics requires "pipeline framework". But this question was not about Genomics but about `parallel` and the way it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can be certain.

The `--block` parameter is described here:
https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#chunk-size

The `-L` parameter here:
https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#records

**Quick summary:**
Parallel will always send full lines to each process until the block/buffer capacity is filled.
If you specify a that one record requires several lines (8 in your case), it will fill the buffer capacity in chunks of 8 lines each.

The last block can be smaller than 8 lines, if there are fewer remaining.

**Side note:**
In the case of properly formatted and interleaved `fastq` files, there will always be 8 lines. `fastq` format specifies that each record is 4 lines and paired-end fastq files must contain the same number of records.

Answer (score 0):

@Jonas is right.

But be aware that `-L` is rather slow: GNU Parallel has to examine every single byte of input.

If you can use `--pipepart` GNU Parallel is *way* faster.

Unfortunately you have to do without `-L` and instead use `--recstart`/`--recend` (possibly with `--regexp`) to determine where a record starts.

With FASTA this is easy: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#example-call-program-with-fasta-sequence

With FASTQ and especially interleaved FASTQ  (i-FASTQ) this is harder. I have not seen enough i-FASTQ files to find a general solution, but the idea is:

- Make a regexp that always matches the end of an i-FASTQ record. Use that for `--recend`.
- Make a regexp that always matches the start of an i-FASTQ record. Use that for `--recstart`.
- Make sure *recend+recstart* **only** matches at the border of a record.

Then use:

```
parallel --pipepart -a big.file --regexp --recstart 'starting regexp' --recend 'ending regexp' ...
```

If someone builds such a regexp couple I think it would make it into the example section of GNU Parallel, because it will be generally useful for i-FASTQ processing.

The regexp couple for normal FASTQ can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41707920/363028 but this does not guarantee that R1 and R2 will be kept together. We need to find some feature of seqname that distinguishes between R1 and R2 for all i-FASTQ files.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTQ_format mentions these three variants:

```
@HWUSI-EAS100R:6:73:941:1973#0/1
@EAS139:136:FC706VJ:2:2104:15343:197393 1:Y:18:ATCACG
@EAS139:136:FC706VJ:2:2104:15343:197393 1:N:18:1
```

where '/1' and ' 1:' indicate this is R1.

This should match those:

```
--regexp --recend '\n' --recstart '@.*(/1| 1:.*)\n[A-Za-z\n\.~]'
```

Comment: Is it fine to use `bwa` threading capability without `parallel`?

Comment: @titus I honestly do not know. I would ask on biostars.org, if I were you.